# Playing Hoopla movie's on iPad 4

Tags: appletv

On my husband's iPad 2, we are able to play Hoopla movies on our Apple TV (using AirPlay and mirroring) with no problems, however if we try to use my iPad 4, all movies are fuzzy.  We have compare all settings on both devices and they are the same.  If I play a Hoopla movie on my iPad4 screen only, it works just fine, very clear, not fuzzy at all.

Any help would really be appreciated.  Thanks

Bartye

Answer (score 1):

This is because your iPad has a lower resolution. It has to stretch the iPad's screen to fit onto your TV, while losing some resolution during the streaming. There is no way to fix this because with current software, this just isn't possible.